# How to get the type of element in a byte array or string in the plokhotnyuk lib codec?

Tags: json, scala, parsing

I have a parsed json with codec custom codec of  jsointer (from this issue).
Inside custom codec from (from this issue) I have element of parsed json in

```
  val value = {new String(
    {
      in.nextToken() // Byte
      in.rollbackToken()
      in.readRawValAsBytes() // Array[Byte]
    },
    StandardCharsets.UTF_8
  )}
```

Is it possible to define the type of element (integer, array, map)?

```
["a", "b"] -> array
{"22": "11"} -> map
“test” -> string
678 -> integer
```

For example like in Python

```
print(type(["a", "b"])) -> <class 'list'>
print(type({"22": "11"})) -> <class 'dict'>
```

Comment: @AndriyPlokhotnyuk thank you for the responce. It was helped me.